# Setup laravel app in wordpress website on subfolder with htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to setup a Laravel app in a subfolder of a WordPress website.

The idea is that when a request goes to example.com/{anything}, the WordPress website will respond but if the request is made on example.com/get-started/*, then the Laravel website will handle the request.

I have found a few similar questions online but none of them is working for me. The recent I have tried is [this one from laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/wordpress-and-laravel-on-subfolder).

My root htaccess file is

```
# Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/get-started [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My htaccess from 'get-started' folder is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

htaccess from 'get-started/public' folder is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I open example.com/get-started, it displayes laravel's default 404 page which tells me that the redirection is working but the laravel app doesn't have a corresponding route.

So I give you my web.php file

```
Route::redirect('/', '/step/1')->name('home');

Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/1', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'step1'])->name('1');
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/2', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'step2'])->name('2');
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/3', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'step3'])->name('3');
```

I'm using [this preset](https://laravel-vite.dev/guide/extra-topics/inertia.html) from Laravel.

Comment: Presumably you have another `.htaccess` file at `/get-started/public/.htaccess`? Please update your question to include the contents of this file also.

Comment: @MrWhite, It is the default `.htaccess` file shipped with laravel that's why I didn't upload it initially but I have edited my question to include it as well.

Comment: Your `.htaccess` files look OK. There are a few things that could be tidied up, but nothing that would change the working. This looks like a Laravel routing issue. However, I'm not sure what you mean by "I can prefix all the URLs but then the assets doesn't load."? Any assets associated with your Laravel project should reference the `/get-started/` subdir, assuming that is where they are located... As in your example, `example.com/get-started/build/assets/main.3843b6a5.js` would get rewritten to `example.com/get-started/public/build/assets/main.3843b6a5.js` - which I assume is the intention?

Comment: @MrWhite I have updated the question to simplify it a bit (Check routes/web.php file). When I run the standalone Laravel app on the server, it works fine which leads me to believe that Laravel's routing file is fine. But when I set it up as a subdirectory on the WordPress website, it shows 404. Any suggestion about how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't set this up but I think of 2 options.

1. Change in Laravel config the path of the public folder to /get-started/
2. Much like as wordpress captures path when you install it in sub-directory, you should add somewhere to your .htaccess in get-started/public before the relevant RewriteCond(s):

```
RewriteBase /get-started/
```

Hope it works.

Comment: may be the need of adding an ``Alias`` is also required?

Comment: FWIW the `.htaccess` files look OK to me. You should _not_ add `RewriteBase` directives in either of the subdirectory `.htaccess` files IMO (that would simply create an unnecessary dependence on the parent directory). However, if you do add a `RewriteBase` directive to the `/get-started/public/.htaccess` file then it would need to be `RewriteBase /get-started/public/` (trailing slash optional), not `RewriteBase /get-started/`, since `index.php` is located inside the `public` subdirectory, not the parent directory.

Comment: @OMiShah How would you intend to implement the `Alias`? If you have access to the server config then you could create an `Alias` from `/get-started` to `/get-started/public` - but that is instead of the `/get-started/.htaccess` file, not as well as. (But if you have access to the server config then you'd probably manage this differently to begin with.)

Comment: Yes, the alias needs to be added in the server conf file.

Comment: Adding this doesn't make any difference. Also, @MrWhite is right, I can't make changes in the server conf file. I only have access to the cPanel.